When must I use a comma before "at" as in "Of the three cities, London has the most people, at nearly 9 million."
The main question at the end hasn't been answered yet.
I didn't have much space for the title, so here's the real sentence.

The London subway system, which opened in 1863, is the largest, at 394 kilometers, followed by those in Paris and Tokyo, at 199 and 155 kilometers respectively.

As you can see, there are too many commas in this sentence. That's why I asked native speakers yesterday if I could remove any of them, and some told me that the commas before "at" are not necessary and I should add a comma before "respectively". If we removed them, the sentence would have a better flow:

The London subway system, which opened in 1863, is the largest at 394 kilometers, followed by those in Paris and Tokyo at 199 and 155 kilometers, respectively.

So far, I've always thought that we need those commas because the data given is only extra information. Without them, the sentence is still complete.
So, when can we remove this kind of comma?

Why do you think there are too many commas? It all makes sense to me. If I did edit the commas I would remove the two before "at", but I would definitely not put a comma before respectively. It's simply an adverb that clarifies the sentence.

@PeterKirkpatrick - The AP Style Manual requires authors to include a comma before the word “respectively” at the end of a sentence when making a parallel comparison between multiple items. However, they do not view it as mandatory, considering it a a matter of personal preference, as long as there is consistency throughout the writing. I think this is very much like the case of the Oxford comma. Neither mandatory nor forbidden.

@PeterKirkpatrick I think there are too many commas because if each comma is equivalent to a pause, readers have to pause too many times when reading this.

@KenAdams - the idea that someone reading aloud must always pause when they reach a comma in writing is misleading. The comma is a punctuation mark for separating distinct information. It helps the reader understand how the ideas in the sentence work together. Although many writers benefit from reading aloud commas as pauses while proofreading, a comma does not always represent a pause in a spoken sentence.

What about the aesthetic side of it? I remember reading somewhere on Stack Exchange that: "Commas could be used correctly in the grammatical sense but still be overused." Maybe this is one of these cases?

Eliminate the not immediately relevant "which opened in 1863" if you're concerned about too many pauses, though I'm not sure where that phobia is coming from. Do you mean you think the sentence is too "choppy"?

@TimR Yes, I think that's also a problem, though the main reason why I found the sentence bad was the pauses as I mentioned earlier.

Having googled it, I realized that "choppy sentences" are a series of short sentences, so I'm not sure if that's what you meant here.

I meant choppy in the sense that it's got more than one focal point and is made of relatively short chunks.  I could see where you might want to correlate age with the extent of the system and have two things going on at once, but that was not the case, or was the case only with London.

Oh but I've just realized that we are straying from the main question at the end of the post.

It's a stylistic choice based on what you want to emphasise. You can remove the comma if you consider the actual numbers to be part of the main information you want to put across. If your main point is the comparison only then keep the commas.

To streamline the sentence you could do a couple of things:

At 394 kilometers the London subway system is the largest, followed by the Paris and Tokyo subways at 199 and 155 kilometers, respectively.


I tried to include "which opened in 1863" in my sentence as it's an important feature I need to report. The London subway was the first system opened in the world. I guess writing a second sentence is an option here.

Do you find my sentence "choppy"? Peter and Michael don't seem to think so. If that's true, maybe I don't even have to rewrite my sentence?

Since you mention only one opening date, for London, the sentence seemed lopsided and arbitrary. I'd move the opening dates to another sentence where you talk about their relative ages and make this sentence about their relative sizes, thereby streamlining it.  I found "those in Paris and Tokyo" clunky. The commas are discretionary.

Personally I'd omit the comma between kilometers and respectively as well.

@KenAdams - To note (maybe?) - New York has the 'Subway', Paris has the 'Métro', London has the 'Underground'. American tourists are regularly confused by 'Subway' signs in London inviting them to descend stairs, but instead of an urban underground railway they find merely a walkway under the adjacent busy road to the other side.
